# Printing an extra number

Tags: python

I'm asking the user to enter a number, then printing every even number up to the number entered. problem is if the inputed number is odd then the program prints an extra number.

What's happening?

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
num2 = 0

while num1 > num2:
    num2 += 2
    if num2 % 2 == 0:
        print(num2)
    else:
        num2 -= 2
        print(num2)
```

Comment: btw. Your `if/else` seems redundant: `num2` is *always* even.

Comment: If `num1` is 5, at the third iteration `num2` will be 4 (so the `while` won't exit) but then 6 will be printed. Initialize `num2` to 2, and update it at the bottom of the loop, not at the start. Or simply do `for num2 in range(2, num1+1, 2): print(num2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's settle this problem first step by step

**If else statement is not needed**
Your if else checks if `num2` is even, but since `num2` will always start at `0`, and then be incremented by `2`, it will always be even.
So this is what your code currently does :

```py
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
num2 = 0

while num1 > num2:
    num2 += 2
    print(num2)
```

This should explain better why the program prints an extra number for an even input number.

**Correct version**
A very simple way to correct this code, would be to slightly change the while condition and add `+1` to `num2`

```py
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
num2 = 0

while num1 > num2 + 1:
    num2 += 2
    print(num2)
```

So here, it will print even numbers from `2` to `num1`
If num1 is even, it stops at `num2 == num1 + 1`
If num1 is not even, it stops at `num2 == num1 + 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
num2 = 0

while num1 > num2:
    if num2 % 2 == 0:
        num2 += 2
        if num2 > num1:
            break
        print(num2)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.